# case_when fails to mutate correct value in another column

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a simple table as below.

```
tibble(
"KPI" =c("1 KPI","2 KPI","3 KPI","4 KPI","5 KPI"),
"VALUE" = c(1,500,1,0.20,7.88),
"BENCHMARK" = c(0,473,0,0.39,6.8),
"CRITERIA"= c(">=90%", "Lower than Benchmark", ">=90%","Lower than Benchmark","Higher than Benchmark"),
"APPROVAL" = c( case_when(
(`VALUE` >= 0.9) ~ 1,
             
             (`VALUE` < `BENCHMARK`) ~ 1,
              (`VALUE` >= 0.9) ~ 1,
             (`VALUE` < `BENCHMARK`) ~ 1,
             (`VALUE` > `BENCHMARK`) ~ 1,
             TRUE ~ 0))
)
```

Does anybody know why I do not have `0` for the first criteria "Lower than Benchmark"?

Comment: All your Values are `>= 0.9`, so the first case `(\`VALUE\` >= 0.9) ~ 1` applies and no further cases are checked.

Comment: Also, you only need backticks for non-standard column names (like with spaces or punctuation in the names). You can use `VALUE` instead of `\`VALUE\`` here.

Comment: @GregorThomas, case 4 is 0.2, but there's also `VALUE < BENCHMARK` and `VALUE > BENCHMARK` as conditions, so you'll always get 1s, except if `VALUE == BENCHMARK` and `VALUE < 0.9`. @pRo you're also repeating condition 1 in condition 3, for some reason

Comment: Oops, yeah, I missed row 4. But in row 4 the second case `(\`VALUE\` < \`BENCHMARK\`) ~ 1` makes the result 1... not sure what OP would expect it to be?

Comment: @JuanC please check the CRITERIA column

Comment: @pRo what does the crtieria column have to do with anything? You don't mention it in your text and your code does not use it. If you want to do something with it, you should explain what that is.

Comment: Seems `CRITERIA` is part of your conditions, in which case your conditions should have a form like this: `case_when(CRITERIA == '>=90%' & VALUE >= .9 ~ expected_result1, etc)`. But we need an expected output and a better explanation of your problem to be able to actually help you. Remember that we have no idea what your problem is and your problem is written as if we did

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that the issue is that you needed to specify what the expected criteria value should be, so that you're not getting multiple conditions registering as TRUE. In addition, I think you may have run into issues with using the backticks around the field names in your case_when code. I made the following edit and removed the redundant criteria from your case when and got the correct result:

```
tibble(
    "KPI" =c("1 KPI","2 KPI","3 KPI","4 KPI","5 KPI"),
    "VALUE" = c(1, 500, 1, 0.20, 7.88),
    "BENCHMARK" = c(0, 473, 0, 0.39, 6.8),
    "CRITERIA"= c(">=90%", "Lower than Benchmark", ">=90%","Lower than Benchmark","Higher than Benchmark"),
    "APPROVAL" = case_when(
        (CRITERIA == ">=90%") & (VALUE >= 0.9) ~ 1,
        (CRITERIA == "Lower than Benchmark") & (VALUE < BENCHMARK) ~ 1,
        (CRITERIA == "Higher than Benchmark")& (VALUE > BENCHMARK) ~ 1,
        TRUE ~ 0))
```

The result:

```
# A tibble: 5 x 5
  KPI    VALUE BENCHMARK CRITERIA              APPROVAL
  <chr>  <dbl>     <dbl> <chr>                    <dbl>
1 1 KPI   1         0    >=90%                        1
2 2 KPI 500       473    Lower than Benchmark         0
3 3 KPI   1         0    >=90%                        1
4 4 KPI   0.2       0.39 Lower than Benchmark         1
5 5 KPI   7.88      6.8  Higher than Benchmark        1
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution by creating a `case_when` condition for each criteria and giving indexing to value one by one like

```
case_when(VALUE[1] >=0.9)~1,T ~ 0),
case_when(VALUE[2] <BENCHMARK[2])~1,T ~ 0) ...so on...
```

If there is another solution I would like to hear.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to accomplish, tbh